# 503 Error When Consuming a Web Service via WhatsApp Business

Tags: service, whatsapp

I am developing a chatbot for WhatsApp Business intended for my company. My goal is to create a web service that returns a PDF file. The service works correctly when I test the URL in a browser, but when I try to use it via WhatsApp Business, I encounter a 503 error ("Service Unavailable").

Here is what I have already checked:

- The server does not seem to be overloaded or undergoing maintenance.
- The web server configuration seems correct, including security headers and session management.
- I am not sure about any potential restrictions from WhatsApp Business regarding external links or web services.
  There does not appear to be any network problems between WhatsApp and my server.
- The URL is correctly formatted and accessible via a browser.
- I wonder if there are any specific restrictions imposed by WhatsApp Business or if other developers have encountered similar problems when integrating web services with WhatsApp Business.

Any help or suggestion to diagnose and solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

For the web service to return a PDF file accessible via a link shared in a WhatsApp Business chat, just as it works in a browser.
I'm wondering if this issue is due to specific restrictions of WhatsApp Business on external links or web services, or if others have encountered similar problems.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of the code that you use for creating that request